# How to correctly map an XML file in Azure Data Factory into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure-data-factory

I currently have an Azure Data Factory pipeline set up where its pulling data from Archer using SOAP API. This data comes through as XML and I'm trying to land it into SQL Server.

How it is currently coming through it seems to be putting the ENTIRE XML file into a single cell inside SQL:

[image]

If I had to guess, I think something is wrong with my mapping in Data Factory, but I'm not sure how to address this:

[image]

Any thoughts on this? Do I need to transform it out of XML before it hits SQL or something? Would greatly appreciate some direction on this. Thank you!

EDIT: this is what the XML data currently looks like. I tried to scrub out anything identifiable:
[image]

EDIT2: this is what it looks like when I enable the advanced editor, note that the collection reference dropdown is blank.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Collection reference` option in the mapping tab of the copy activity to unroll and extract data from an XML file. I tried with the sample data as shown below:

[image]

In the mapping tab, follow the procedure below:

- In the mapping tab, select **Import schemas**
- Toggle on the **Advanced editor**
- Provide the JSON path of the array from which data needs to be iterated and extracted, as shown below:

[image]

After debugging the pipeline, XML data is copied to the SQL server, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bhavani I think this gets me 90% of the way there. I had a question on the JSON path for the array. The XML output I'm using does not contain anything in the format of $['text']['row']. Is this something I should manually convert? I'd just want to make sure my XML file will correctly be able to read this.

Comment: Could you please provide your sample XML data?

Comment: I have added an edit picture of the XML in the OP. It seems like all the column headers are preceded by "name="

Comment: any advice for how to format my XML? I provided an example in OP.

Comment: could you please provide your xml in text fotmat?

Comment: I cannot provide the actual XML file, as there is some sensitive information in it. I was hoping that the screenshot would provide enough information. I was hoping the consistent format of "name="Third Party" alias="Third_Party"" would provide enough context on how to format correctly.

Comment: Once toggle on the advance editor check for collect reference as shown in above image provide what collect reference you are getting.

Comment: I have toggled on the advanced editor and added a screenshot above, the collection reference dropdown is blank. The source does pre-populate with this: $['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['SearchRecordsByReportResponse']['SearchRecordsByReportResult']

Comment: Make sure your xml is in the correct format, if it is not, then   you are not able to get collection reference.